# Fastest string comparison in sql case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a straight forward `SELECT` query. Now i need to change values in one column based on another varchar column.

Here an example:

```
SELECT
  Company_Name,

  CASE 
    WHEN Size = 'Large' THEN Company_Name 
    ELSE 'Small company'
  end,

  CASE 
    WHEN left (Size,1) = 'L' THEN Company_Name 
    ELSE 'Small company'
  end,

  CASE 
    WHEN ASCII(Size) = 76 THEN Company_Name 
    ELSE 'Small company'
  end,

  Size
FROM MyTable
```

Here I have 3 `CASE`s. Which one is faster? This query is for data extract and it has no `WHERE` clause.

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

Q: Why I cannot do it by running against a table?

A:

1. Running a query on a given dataset does not prove solution is faster for any data set.
2. I do not have permissions to reset DB, so test runs are comparable: `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`

Comment: Just use each case separately in query and run them. See which one return faster. No other way of answering this.

Comment: *"Here I have 3 $foos. Which one is faster?"* - Have you measured?

Comment: I am at development stage and my table is too small to measure at the moment.

Comment: @Stoleg Then fill your table with test data ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Hmmmmm... If I could do it I would have already done it. Do you think empiric method is the only way here?

Comment: @Tomalak, I cannot do comparable measurements.

Comment: Due to the large number of variables, nearly all performance tuning (beyond the obvious) is heavily dependent on the environment.

Comment: @EricHauenstein, can you please elaborate. These are deterministic functions. Environment has plenty of RAM and CPU.

Comment: It depends on the length of `Size` column's data - `NVARCHAR(10)`, `NVARCHAR(4000)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, etc. - the longer strings more time needed to compare them. But if strings are short the first `CASE` seemed to be the fastest because any `CASE` requires retrieving column data before running function (`LEFT`, `ASCII`) and comparison. But I think it doesn't matter which one you use until you have less than hundreds of millions records and slow hardware. In such case you should rearrange data structure to definitely obtain result in required time - make reference table with possible `Sizes`.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any significant difference between the three options for normal volume of data. I tested this on a table with 10 million records.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sizes
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Size NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @i INT;
SET @i = 0;
WHILE @i < 10000000
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.Sizes (Size)
        VALUES (N'Small'), (N'Medium'), (N'Large');
    SET @i = @i + 3;
END
```

First test.

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO

SELECT ID, 
        CASE
            WHEN Size = N'Large' THEN CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(25))
            ELSE N'Small company'
        END AS 'SizeDescription',
        Size
    FROM dbo.Sizes;
GO

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
GO
```

Results for first test.

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

(10000002 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 7422 ms,  elapsed time = 64791 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

Second test.

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO

SELECT ID, 
        CASE
            WHEN LEFT(Size,1) = N'L' THEN CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(25))
            ELSE N'Small company'
        END AS 'SizeDescription',
        Size
    FROM dbo.Sizes;
GO

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
GO
```

Results from second test.

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

(10000002 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 8203 ms,  elapsed time = 69081 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

Third test.

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO

SELECT ID, 
        CASE
            WHEN ASCII(Size) = 76 THEN CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(25))
            ELSE N'Small company'
        END AS 'SizeDescription',
        Size
    FROM dbo.Sizes;
GO

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
GO
```

Results from third test.

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

(10000002 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 8031 ms,  elapsed time = 69460 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

The CPU time is the critical measurement and this is much the same for the three tests (between 7.4 and 8.2 seconds).

If you needed to speed up the query, you could reduce the size of the Size field by replacing it with a single character or tinyint. This would reduce the overall size of the table and speed up I/O.

You'd also need to consider the time taken to return the results which likely to be the limiting factor. And indeed locking on the table--are other users updating the table at the same time as running the queries?

Comment: Can you please add logical/physical reads stats. Did you do `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` between tests?

Comment: @Stoleg Why don't you take what I've done, do more some experimentation, and share the results here? However I think you are worrying unnecessarily about any possible minute differences between the three options you asked about. If you wanted to give more information, it would help to advise you. Table structure, data volumes, purpose of application, reporting requirements, updating volumes, etc.

Comment: @Stoleg If the problem is that you don't have access to a SQL Server for testing, there are at least three options: you can download a free SQL Server Express, a 180 day free trial of SQL Server Developer Edition, or sign up for a free account with Microsoft Azure.